# AVSpeechSynthesizer not presenting new view controller upon completion

Tags: ios, xcode, avspeechsynthesizer

I've implemented AVSpeechSynthesizer in a project of mine. The code works until it gets to the synthesizer's **didFinishSpeechUtterance** delegate method. Now, I'm not sure if it's being called or not. It's possible that it is being called, but my code for presenting a new view controller upon the utterance's completion isn't correctly written within the delegate method. I know my code for presenting a new view controller is correct, because it works everywhere else, except here. Any ideas?

```
-(void)speechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)synthesizer didFinishSpeechUtterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance{

InfoGreetView *displayGuestMessageView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"guestMessageView"];
displayGuestMessageView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:displayGuestMessageView animated:YES completion:nil]; }
```

Comment: Try putting a break point there so you can be sure whether its being called or not. If its called than you might want to do the process in main queue.

Comment: Bhumit, I've set up a breakpoint,  but my debugger isn't showing me any output for some reason. Can you elaborate on your comment about doing the process in the main queu, please?